# What is this syntax ? [0]+ in front of training_histories_fixed_iterations[i].history[‘accuracy’]

Tags: python, matplotlib, syntax

I passed by a piece of code that is puzzling me.
There is a training history according to iterations in an DL model. And in

```
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 9000, 9000/epochs[i]), [0]+ training_histories_fixed_iterations[i].history[‘accuracy’], label =batch_size[i])
```

So the idea is to understand what is the [0]+ in this syntax of plotting.

This was actually puzzling and the answer is very simple but it could have been different

Comment: It's `[0]` (a list) `+` (concatenation) `training_histories_fixed_iterations[i].history['accuracy']` (which is presumably another list).